# How to prove that a particular form of numbers achieve all remainders modulo $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

(Note: Here numbers mean positive integers, all variables used are positive integers)

This query is regarding a particular question where I need to prove that a particular form of numbers ("particular form of numbers", for example squares, cubes, $4n+1$ etc.) can attain every remainder modulo $n$ for some positive integer $n$.

So my question is, what is the general process to approach this type of problem?

For example suppose we need to find the type of numbers $k$ for which the sequence $1^2, 2^2, 3^2 , \cdots $ contains all the remainders modulo $k$.
(That is , the equation
$r^2 = x \pmod k$ has a solution $r$ for all $x=1,2, \cdots k$).

So far, I have not been able to make any rigourous proof. So please give some general method to approach these type of question.

Comment: There isn't any $k>2$ for which the squares contain all the remainders, since $x^2$ and $(k-x)^2$ have the same remainder.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what you are asking. For some conditions (eg numbers are squares) the answer is trivial. For cubes it would be a bit more interesting. But without being more specific, there is no hope of a general method. I think Hardy and Wright "Introduction to the theory of numbers" has a good basic account of solving polynomial congruences.

Comment: Would you like to engage with the comments, Aditya?

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't reply that time. Ok so Gerry Myerson can you please explain your comment a bit? Why does  $x^2$ and $(k-x)^2 $ having the same remainder force some remainders to never occur?

Comment: Mark Bennet,  I was actually thinking about triangular numbers.

Comment: If a map from a finite set to itself is not one-one, then it can't be onto, Aditya. And if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to include @Gerry in it.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson , yes but how is this a finite set? And how is this a map from a set to itself?  We are trying to work on the entire infinite sequence of squares, aren't we?

Comment: You're asking about the remainders modulo $k$. For each $k$, that's a finite set. The map that takes $x$ to $x^2$ is a map from this finite set to itself. And it can't be onto (for $k\ge3$) since it's not one-one.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, the map that takes $x$ to $x^2$ is an infinite set right? See I'm trying to say that we have all the infinitely many numbers $1,4,9,16,\cdots$ and we need to check say for $k=5$, if all the remainders modulo $5$ exist or not. Now can you please explain your method with respect to this example?

Comment: For $k=5$, you only have to look at $1,4,9,16,25$ – after that, you just keep getting the same remainders in the same order over and over again forever. Try it, and see! More generally, if $x$ and $y$ have the same remainder on division by $k$, then $x^2$ and $y^2$ have the same remainder on division by $k$, so you only have to look at $1^2,2^2,\dots,k^2$ to get the full picture. Everything beyond that just repeats, cyclically, what you've already seen.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson oh right! Now I get it.. Just one small question. You said that map from a finite set to itself can't be onto if it is one one. But here in this case aren't we thnking about two different finite sets of the same cardinality? ( The argument still holds, I'm just trying to verify if I've understood it correctly). The first finite set is $A=\{(5n)^2, (5n+1)^2 , \cdots ,(5n+4)^2\} $ for some integer $n$ and the other is $B=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: Can't be onto if it **isn't** one-one. And I was mapping from $A=\{\,0,1,2,\dots,k-1\,\}$ to the set of possible remainders when you divide (the squares) by $k$, and that set is also $A$ – but it works your way, too, as a map from a finite set to any other finite set with the same cardinality is one-one if and only if it is onto.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, ok got it. Thank you !

Comment: Good. You could write it up, and post it as a (partial) answer to your question. Or think about ways to generalize it.

Comment: You could do that today!

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, yes I am doing it. I was just trying to generalise it to $n$th power of numbers. So could prove that the $n$ power numbers when $n$ is even, can't contain all the remainders modulo $k$. Now I was trying to work out how to work with odd $n$ which is taking some time. Nevertheless, I have posted my partial progress on the problem( i.e.  for even indices) now.

Comment: Start with $n=3$ and $k$ being prime.

Comment: Look for example at $k=5$ and $k=7$ (and $n=3$), and think about why they work out differently.

Answer (score 0):

Partial progress :
Here's the proof that $n$ power numbers for any even $n>1$ (i.e. squares, $4$ th powers etc.)  can't achieve all remainders modulo $k$ for $k \gt 2$.

Define sets $A$ and $B$ as
$A=\{ km, km+1, \cdots , km+k-1 \} $
$B=\{ 0,1,2 \cdots , k-1 \}$.
See that $|A|=|B|$.

Define a map $p : A \mapsto B$  such that $p(a)=r$ where $ a^n \equiv r \pmod k$.

For any $a \in A$,
Note that
$a^n \equiv (k-a)^n \pmod k$.  (Since $n$ is even, it is trivial by binomial theorem)

$\implies p $ is not a one one map and because $|A|=|B|$, $p$ can not be onto.